# Default values for mouseX and mouseY in p5js

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to set a default value for mouseX and mouseY. I want my blob to appear in the center of the screen, and then when the user moves the cursor, it moves from there.
When I do this:

```
pmouseX,500
```

it places in that position but when I move my mouse it doesn't move.
It is possible to do?

Comment: You would need to show more code to get help. What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You should post some more of your code to get some real help. In the meantime take a look at this example: https://p5js.org/examples/input-mouse-functions.html. Make sure you're updating the mouse offset to get the new position. Best of luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).